# format string to another string format

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, filter, format

I want the newValue to keep the maskValue format, with spaces.

I have for example these two strings, the expected outcome would be this:

```
   maskValue: "0 0000 0000 0000" <= initial maskValue

   rawValue: "251551220"

   As i type the maskValue changes to: "2 5155 1220 0000"

   newValue = "2 5155 1220" <= expected result

   2 5155 1220 0000 <= current result, it adds the rest of the zeros
```

This is my code:

```
const formattedValue = (maskValue.split('').filter(
            val => val === ' ' || rawValue.split('').includes(val)
          ))
            .join('');
```

Thanks for the help in advance

Answer (score 1):

```js
const maskValue = "0 0000 0000 0000"
const rawValue = "251551220"

const result = []

const pieces = maskValue.split(' ').map(piece => piece.length)

const slice = (str, pieces) => {
  let secondPiece = str
  pieces.forEach(piece => {
    const firstPiece = secondPiece.slice(0, piece)
    result.push(firstPiece)
    secondPiece = secondPiece.slice(piece);
  })
}

slice(rawValue, pieces)

const rawValueWithMask = result.join(' ')

console.log(rawValueWithMask)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this approach:

```
const formattedValue = rawValue.replace(/^(\d{1})(\d{4})(\d{4}).*/, '$1 $2 $3');
```

Comment: Thanks, for the input. but the maskValue is dynamic, so it can be different all the time

Comment: No problem, In that case maybe you should use a library.

Answer (score 0):

I would determine the length of the final formattedValue first:

```
const blankSpaceCount = maskValue.substr(0, rawValue.length).split('').filter(x => x === ' ').length;
const formattedValueLength = rawValue.length + blankSpaceCount;
```

At the end you can just use `substr` to reduce the size of the final string:

```
formattedValue.substr(0, formattedValueLength)
```

This works dynamically with whatever input is coming.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can format a string using a mask, without having tailing zeros for remaining chars:

```
const maskValue = '0 0000 0000 0000'
const rawValue = '251551220'

let maskIndex = 0
let formattedValue = ''
rawValue.split('').forEach(char => {
  if (maskIndex < maskValue.length && maskValue[maskIndex] === ' ') {
    formattedValue += ' '
    maskIndex++
  }
  formattedValue += char
  maskIndex++
})

console.log(formattedValue)
```